# Status code 500 при использовании цикла

Tags: python, парсер

Получаю статус код таким способом:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import requests

url = 'https://invidious.snopyta.org/api/v1/channels/UCAL3JXZSzSm8AlZyD3nQdBA'

header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0'}

r = requests.get(url, headers=header)

print('Status code:', r.status_code)
```

После запуска получаю ответ: "Status code: 200". Хорошо. Теперь создаю файл и добавляю 2 одинаковых ссылки и прохожу в цикле:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import requests

header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0'}

f = open('Test/invidious.txt')
for line in f:
    r = requests.get(line, headers=header)
    print('Status code:', r.status_code)
    print(r.text)
```

И в ответ получаю:

```
Status code: 500
{"error":"Header content contains invalid character '\\n'","errorBacktrace":"Header content contains invalid character '\\n' (ArgumentError)\n  from ../../../usr/share/crystal/src/http/headers.cr:337:7 in 'check_invalid_header_content'\n  from ../../../usr/share/crystal/src/http/headers.cr:59:5 in '[]='\n  from lib/lsquic/src/lsquic/client.cr:470:7 in 'set_defaults'\n  from lib/lsquic/src/lsquic/client.cr:455:7 in 'send_request'\n  from lib/lsquic/src/lsquic/client.cr:416:7 in 'exec_internal_single'\n  from lib/lsquic/src/lsquic/client.cr:409:7 in 'exec_internal'\n  from lib/lsquic/src/lsquic/client.cr:405:7 in 'exec'\n  from lib/lsquic/src/lsquic/client.cr:486:7 in 'exec'\n  from lib/lsquic/src/lsquic/client.cr:342:5 in 'get'\n  from src/invidious/channels.cr:798:29 in 'get_about_info'\n  from src/invidious.cr:2268:15 in '->'\n  from ../../../usr/share/crystal/src/primitives.cr:255:3 in '->'\n  from ../../../usr/share/crystal/src/primitives.cr:255:3 in 'process_request'\n  from lib/kemal/src/kemal/route_handler.cr:17:7 in 'call'\n  from ../../../usr/share/crystal/src/http/server/handler.cr:28:7 in 'call_next'\n  from lib/kemal/src/kemal/websocket_handler.cr:13:14 in 'call'\n  from ../../../usr/share/crystal/src/http/server/handler.cr:28:7 in 'call_next'\n  from lib/kemal/src/kemal/filter_handler.cr:21:7 in 'call'\n  from ../../../usr/share/crystal/src/http/server/handler.cr:28:7 in 'call_next'\n  from src/invidious/helpers/handlers.cr:212:5 in 'call'\n  from ../../../usr/share/crystal/src/http/server/handler.cr:28:7 in 'call_next'\n  from src/invidious/helpers/handlers.cr:94:12 in 'call'\n  from ../../../usr/share/crystal/src/http/server/handler.cr:28:7 in 'call_next'\n  from src/invidious/helpers/handlers.cr:158:7 in 'call'\n  from ../../../usr/share/crystal/src/http/server/handler.cr:28:7 in 'call_next'\n  from src/invidious/helpers/handlers.cr:70:5 in 'call'\n  from ../../../usr/share/crystal/src/http/server/handler.cr:28:7 in 'call_next'\n  from src/invidious/helpers/static_file_handler.cr:189:11 in 'call'\n  from ../../../usr/share/crystal/src/http/server/handler.cr:28:7 in 'call_next'\n  from lib/kemal/src/kemal/exception_handler.cr:8:7 in 'call'\n  from ../../../usr/share/crystal/src/http/server/handler.cr:28:7 in 'call_next'\n  from src/invidious/helpers/logger.cr:19:35 in 'call'\n  from ../../../usr/share/crystal/src/http/server/handler.cr:28:7 in 'call_next'\n  from lib/kemal/src/kemal/init_handler.cr:12:7 in 'call'\n  from ../../../usr/share/crystal/src/http/server/request_processor.cr:50:11 in 'process'\n  from ../../../usr/share/crystal/src/http/server.cr:513:5 in 'handle_client'\n  from ../../../usr/share/crystal/src/http/server.cr:468:13 in '->'\n  from ../../../usr/share/crystal/src/primitives.cr:255:3 in 'run'\n  from ../../../usr/share/crystal/src/fiber.cr:92:34 in '->'\n  from ???\n"}
```

Почему в первом случае все хорошо, а во втором выводит ошибку? С такой ошибкой советуют посмотреть header через обычный браузер и подставить их в код, но мне это не помогло. Что можно попробовать?

Ответ: вместо
`r = requests.get(line, headers=header)` нужно использовать
`r = requests.get(line.strip(), headers=header)`

Comment: Потому что `for line in fp` возвращает строки вместе с символом переноса строки (`'\n'`).

Comment: И лучше сразу учитесь правильно работать с файлами: `with open('Test/invidious.txt') as f:`

Answer (score 1):

Ответ: вместо

```
r = requests.get(line, headers=header)
```

нужно использовать

```
r = requests.get(line.strip(), headers=header)
```